# Attach image on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to attach image with mouse once i click or drag.
alert is my problem, without alert its not working, but i need same functionality without alert.

[**This fiddle will make you clear.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Sx9Lb/1/)

```
$('#drag .drg1').draggable({
    cursor: 'move',      
    revert: 'invalid',     
    revertDuration: 900,
    zIndex:100,
    start: function(event, ui) {
        alert("hi");
    } 
});
```

please help....thanks

Comment: I don't see how alert() fix something??? In both case in your jsfiddle, i get same result, so what is your issue?

Comment: Seems to work just fine without the alerts. What is not working?

Comment: i want functionality if you assume that there is no alert pop up. but without alert image is not sticking with the cursor. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```
<img id="imgImage" src="#">
<a href="#" id="btnLoad">Load Image</a>
<script>

    $( '#btnLoad' ).bind( 'click', function( e ) {

        $( 'imgImage' ).attr( 'src', 'img.jpg' );

    });

</script>
```

Comment: that is only changing image...i need image to stick to mouse which i have clicked.